# Pass multiple variable groups to sub-template in Azure Devops YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using template approach in our build and release pipelines. We have defined separate build as well as release templates.
Currently passing one variable group from main yaml pipeline to template as a parameter.

```
variables:
  - ${{ if item.variablesGroup }}:
    - group: ${{ item.variablesGroup }}
```

In above code, item is the iterator, and variablesGroup is being passed as parameter. This works fine.

I pass this variable group in this way,

```
stages:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    environments:
      - name: test
        variablesGroup: variable-group-name
```

Pipelines usually allow us to use multiple variable groups as,

```
variables:
  - group: variable-group-1
  - group: variable-group-2
```

My ask is, how can we pass multiple variable groups to template, and then utilize it? I can pass this as a comma-separated value from main pipeline, but then how to utilize it in template?

Comment: can you please the yaml snippet of how are you currently passing the variable group to your template?

Comment: @Sibtain 
stages:
    - template: my-template.yml
      parameters:
        environments:
          - name: test
            variablesGroup: variable-group-name

Comment: this isn't readable in comments, please edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can be passed as `object` type as well which means `any YAML structure` can be supported. One of the ways you can achieve this is by using the below technique.

**my-template.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: 'varGroups'
  type: object
  default: {}

stages:
- stage: build
  variables: ${{ parameters.varGroups }}
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello world
```

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
stages:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    varGroups:
    - group: myVariableGroup
    - group: myVariableGroup2
```

See the examples in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameter-data-types) for more details.